# Which opensource alternative for users used to ArcGIS 10.x?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations

I'm a student and used ArcMap 10 for over 5 years now. Since I will finish university in 3-4 month I wouldn't be able to use ArcMap free of charge anymore. I already searched on google for opensource alternatives (found QGIS, Grass, SAGA and some more) but I'm unsure which one I should give a try. The software should be opensource and easy to use for someone who used ESRI products before.

**Can anybody recommend a product?**

Comment: I think questions asking for software recommendations are more suited to being asked at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange because it uses question asking guidelines that are more tuned to getting objective rather than opinion-based answers.

Comment: Alternatively, you could research/ask one or more focussed questions here, with each being about a specific requirement that you are concerned a candidate for your open source desktop GIS may not be able to meet.

Comment: I thought asking here would be the best way to get qualified answers by people using different GIS solutions. I downloaded QGIS as suggested by jbgramm and Simon and will try that.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with QGIS.
The interface is somewhat similar to ArcGIS, most of the functionality is there either in the main program, or with add-ins.
There is an active development road map, and there are frequent, productive, and sometimes profound updates.
Much of the functionality found in Grass, and Saga, can be found in QGIS with the processing toolbox.
You have a group of really motivated, and helpful people here that are able to answer questions, and there are books available that will help with usage, and programming for very reasonable cost.

I am a very experienced ArcGIS, Mapinfo, Manifold, QGIS, Saga, and Global Mapper user, and if I was going to start out with anything knowing what I know now, I would invest heavily in hardware, and use QGIS as my software of choice.  I would also investigate Radian/Manifold 9 when they are released.
They are not free, but some of the new developments are truly ground breaking, and the price will be reasonable given their past history.

You have true 64 bit capabilities in QGIS, Manifold, Global Mapper, and now finally in Mapinfo, and somewhat in ArcGIS.

The vision seems much clearer to me in the first three packages, and the cost of entry if you decide to pay for software is much lower, or non-existent besides your time to learn the software.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what exactly you want to do in GIS. I'm in pretty much the same situation: learned to use ArcGIS 10.x (currently 10.3) at university and searching for a free of charge software I could use next year when I graduate.
I started using QGIS a year ago and was able to fulfill most of the tasks I usually completed in ArcMap before. Maybe you want to give QGIS a try, there are also many plug-ins available which expand the functionality.

Maybe you could outline what your main tasks are you usually work on in ArcMap so people could give you better recommendations.

If you want a pretty comprehensive overview of available GIS solutions, maybe this link is helpful: http://gisgeography.com/mapping-out-gis-software-landscape/